# jQuery UI dialog z-index problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to get a dialog to appear over a dialog in jQuery. The problem that i'm having is when the top dialog is opened the z-indexes are wrong so the div with the class ui-widget-overlay appears behind the first dialog instead of behind the second dialog.

Here is a breakdown of the z-indexes:

I will refer to the first dialog opened as dialog#1 and the one opened on top of this as dialog#2 and the ui-widget-overlays as  ui-widget-overlay#1 and ui-widget-overlay#2 respectively.

dialog#1 is opened and its z-index is set as 1 with ui-widget-overlay#1 z-index set as 0

dialog#2 is opened and its z-index is set as 1 with ui-widget-overlay#2 z-index set as 0

Then when i close dialog#2 and re open it, this time dialog#2 z-index is correctly set as 2 and ui-widget-overlay#2 is correctly set as 1

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, is there a jquery-ui setting I am missing to tell it to increment the z-indexes for subsequent dialogs?

**Edit:** 
I also wanted to point out that i have set `stack:true` in the dialog options and it has made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had to use a bit of a hack to get this working as intended.

Basically i added an event when the modal is created so the dialog initialisation is something like:

```
  dialogWindow.dialog({
      modal: true,
      create: function(event, ui) {
          dialogWindow.parent('.ui-dialog').css('zIndex', 2)
              .nextAll('.ui-widget-overlay').css('zIndex', 1);
      }
    });
```

Thanks to the below post for giving me this answer.

[How to fix the zIndex issue with jQuery Dialog UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988447/how-to-fix-the-zindex-issue-with-jquery-dialog-ui)